# RSA in pollynomial time

Tags: rsa

If we know the RSA encryption of messages m, m+1, m+2 when c=3, how can we compute m in polynomial time?

Comment: I assume by `c`, you mean the public exponent (which is more conventionally known as `e`)

Comment: HINT: Write the three cipher texts as polynomials in $m$. Look for a linear combination of these that is linear in $m$.